Desktop application is disappeared after using second display
Although I installed such a file at the following, it doesn't appear since the second monitor was adapted on my laptop.
$ ls ~/Desktop/
Studio.desktop  VSCode.desktop
$ cat ~/Desktop/*
[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Terminal=false
Name=Android Studio
Exec=/playground/android-studio/bin/studio.sh
Path=/playground/lin/android
Icon=/playground/android-studio/bin/studio.png

[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Terminal=false
Name=Visual Studio Code
Exec=code
Path=/Developments/VSC-Projects
Icon=~/Pictures/visual-studio-code-icons/vscode.png

It is not a solution that I disconnect the second one.
Then, is it helpful for use other gnome extension of debian package?
